# Spring define property of interface no implementation

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, interface

I have class with data member with property of interface no implementation,
How can I define this property?

I tried with `@Autowired`, but when I run it in junit - it's throw an Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [bean name] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

//my class is :
@Service
@Component(value="someClass")
@Transactional
public class someClass implements SomeService, InitializingBean {
    @Autowired
    private SomeInterface someInterface ;
}

//and the interface with no implementation:
public interface SomeInterface extends CrudRepository<AAA, String> {
}
```

Comment: You have to configure or create a bean. Can you show some more code.

Comment: I attached my code above

Answer (score 0):

Have you told Spring about your Repository? In Spring Boot I would do this:

```
//and the interface with no implementation:
@Repository
@Qualifier(value = "someInterface") //Should this not be someOtherRepository ???
public interface SomeInterface extends someRepository<AAA, String> {
}
```

If SomeInterface is a repository that extends another Repository Interface that you have defined I think you have to annotate the intermediate repository with @NoRepositoryBean. At least in Spring boot, see the documentation here [Example 7. Selectively exposing CRUD methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: I add it, but still it's not work. the Exception is:  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [SomeInterface] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Can you post your configuration? Are you using xml or java config?

Comment: I use only with java config

Comment: Do you have @EnableJpaRepositories anywhere in your config?

Comment: Or @EnableRepositories? It might help if you post your config in your question.

Comment: now it works for me, the problem was with @EnableJpaRepositories,